# Deprecation of VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D's points

Tags: face-recognition, ios11, vision

I have installed Xcode beta 5. Now I have a warning related to Vision framework and `VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D` object especially:

> 'point(at:)' was deprecated in iOS 11.0

Regarding to documentation `point(at:)` and `points` were introduced and deprecated in iOS 11. Anyway, now I can get a face landmark points?

Comment: It looks like we're supposed to use the `normalizedPoints` property instead, but for some reason this is only available to Objective-C developers at this time. Lovely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In last Xcode updates `VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D` was changed. And now it is no needed to convert x and y into `CGPoint` object. `VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D` has `normalizedPoints`, an array of `CGPoint`s.

Comment: Why in every `normalizedPoints` return 12 points? What are they showing? How can I convert them to a CGPoint to show on screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the alternative for points(at:) like this:

```
if let landmark = face.landmarks?.leftEye {
        for i in 0...landmark.pointCount - 1 { // last point is 0,0
            let point = landmark.normalizedPoints[i]
            if i == 0 {
                context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h))
            } else {
                context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h))
            }
        }
    }
```